# A simple probability question but seemingly 2 answers, which one is the best?

Tags: probability-theory

A fair spinner with digits  1,2,2,3 marked on it is spun three times. The three numbers are added to give a score. Find the probability that the score is even.

Answer 1 : There are 32 even outcomes eg 3,2,1.......

so P(even score ) is 32/64  = 1/2.

Answer 2: There are 13 even scores eg. 2+2+2 therefore 13/64.

Is this a case of equally likely or not? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

No matter whether the score after two spins is even or odd, the probability for an even or odd score will be $\frac{1}{2}$ each at the last spin.

Hence $\frac{1}{2}$ is the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how  you counted the scores, but since there are Two odd numbers and two even ones, the answer is $\frac12$.

Answer (score 0):

The different possible scores aren't equally probable. And there aren't 64 of them either (you can get anywhere from $3$ to $9$, which makes it $7$ different possible scores, and three of them are even). So that approach is not going to work without massive changes.

The first approach is better, because each of the $64$ outcomes (assuming you, for a moment, pretend like the two $2$'s are different $2$'s) are equally likely. You just have to be careful when adding them up so that you are *certain* that exactly $32$ of them result in an even sum.

My preferred approach: After the first two spins, the last spin will decide whether the sum is even or odd. It has an equal probability of deciding either way, so the probability of an even sum is $\frac12$.